# Haskell error with cabal: no instance for

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to follow the steps for installation for derivation of software product lines called [hephaestus-pl](https://github.com/hephaestus-pl/hephaestus-base). However, at the time of performing the installation steps, according to the tutorial, there is an error when executing the `cabal install` command on all cloned repositories. The erros is:

```
$ sudo cabal install
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
/home/notebook/workspace/hephaestus/hephaestus-sb
Configuring funsat-0.6.2...
Building funsat-0.6.2...
Failed to install funsat-0.6.2
Build log ( /home/notebook/workspace/hephaestus/hephaestus-sb/logs/funsat-0.6.2.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '.'
Configuring funsat-0.6.2...
Building funsat-0.6.2...
Preprocessing library funsat-0.6.2...
[ 4 of 10] Compiling Funsat.Monad     ( src/Funsat/Monad.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-cf02e0bc/build/Funsat/Monad.o )

src/Funsat/Monad.hs:64:10: error:
    • No instance for (Applicative (SSTErrMonad e st s))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Monad (SSTErrMonad e st s)’

src/Funsat/Monad.hs:88:10: error:
    • Could not deduce (GHC.Base.Alternative (SSTErrMonad e st s))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: Error e
        bound by the instance declaration at src/Funsat/Monad.hs:88:10-52
    • In the instance declaration for ‘MonadPlus (SSTErrMonad e st s)’
cabal: Leaving directory '.'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
funsat-0.6.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I'm using the following version of `ghci`, which came installed along with the `haskell-platform:`

```
$ ghci 
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
```

The cabal version is:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.1
compiled using version 1.24.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

My operating system is `debian 9.2`.

Comment: funsat 0.6.2 was released in 2011, so no wonder it cannot be compiled in latest ghc. Looking into the [commit history](https://github.com/dbueno/funsat/commits/master), there seems version 0.6.3. which is not yet released in hackage. You can give it a try.

Comment: @ymonad To be fair, C code written years ago probably still compiles just fine today. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is failing to compile due to the [Functor/Applicative/Monad proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) implemented in more recent versions of GHC. The code would originally have compiled just fine, but in recent versions of GHC, you cannot declare something as `Monad` without first declaring it as `Functor` and `Applicative`. You used to be able to, but now you cannot.

The library authors need to update the library's code to fix this new restriction.